# @safe-global/protocol-kit Create2 error using deploySafe and nodejs

Tags: nodejs, gnosis-safe, goerli

I'm using nodejs and deploying the createSafe function as so:

```
async function createSafe(ethAdapter) {
    try {
        const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter });
        const ownerAddress = await ethAdapter.getSignerAddress();
        const safeAccountConfig = {
            owners: [ownerAddress, "0xBD95F8B5242f440354e4E1ac8D2DCf30070cF97F"],
            threshold: 2,
        };
        const safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig, options: { gasLimit: 3000000 } });
        return safe;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

I'm setting up my wallet and provider using ethers and alchemy like this

```
async function getProvider(network) {
    if (networks[network] === undefined) {
        throw new Error("Invalid network");
    }
    return new providers.AlchemyProvider(network, process.env.ALCHEMY_KEY);
}

async function getEthersAdapter(wallet) {
    try {
        const ethersAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signerOrProvider: wallet });
        return ethersAdapter;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

```
async function loadWallet(privateKey, provider) {
    wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    return wallet;
}
```

And my test is like so

```
describe("Gnosis Safe", () => {
    describe("#createSafe", async () => {
        const network = "arbitrum-goerli";
        const provider = await getProvider(network);
        const pKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
        const wallet = await loadWallet(pKey, provider);
        console.log(wallet);
        const ethAdapter = await getEthersAdapter(wallet);
        console.log(ethAdapter);
        const safe = await createSafe(ethAdapter);
```

See transaction hash for the Create2 call failed error here: https://goerli-optimism.etherscan.io/tx/0xd6646dc55302f1be61140667e7f5c8bc0077faa6423954084699f2bd588d25a6

Any idea why I'm getting a Create2 call error? Any thoughts on how to debug this? I'm new to using nodejs, ethers, and gnosis safe contracts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this StackExchange question regarding why a create2 call might revert:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160798/why-would-create2-revert

In your case, the reason is number 2) since all the deployment parameters are static, and I can see a previously successful deployment transaction on the account you linked.

https://goerli-optimism.etherscan.io/tx/0x4394be4a0cae9e971856431e4970c66b2d0970411e735c109f97f4ffcdc7eede